# listen to changes in response object from the custom hook with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am quite new to react and I have the following custom hook that I have to use.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const wait = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const useSubmit = () => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);

    const submit = async (url, data) => {
        const random = Math.random();
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            await wait(2000);
            if (random < 0.5) {
                throw new Error("Something went wrong");
            }
            setResponse({
                type: 'success',
                message: `Thanks for your submission ${data.firstName}, we will get back to you shortly!`,
            })
        } catch (error) {
            setResponse({
                type: 'error',
                message: 'Something went wrong, please try again later!',
            })
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return { isLoading, response, submit };
}

export default useSubmit;
```

Then on a form component using formik I'm trying to call the submit() on onSubmit:

```
    const { isLoading, response, submit } = useSubmit();

    const formik = useFormik({

        onSubmit: (values, actions) => {      
            submit("", values);
        }
    });
```

After calling submit I need to get the response set in the submit function, what is the best practise to call the submit and listen to the response object. Should I use a useEffect checking the response or is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the response set in the response variable itself, you can just console.log(response) after submit("", values);